# Probability: Baye's Rule

Tags: probability-theory, bayes-theorem

A key is equally likely to be in one of four bins. αi is the probability that you find the key in bin i after looking for it in bin i. (0<= αi <= 1)

You look in bins 2 and 4 and do not find the key. What is the probability that the key is either in bin 2 or 4?

==================

I'm thinking of Baye's rule

Bi - event that the key is in bin i (i=1,2,3,4)

E - event that you do not find the key in bins 2 and 4 after examining these two bins

then the desired probability is 
$$
\begin{align*}
P(B2\cup B4\mid E)&=P(B2\mid E)+P(B4\mid E)\\&=\frac{P(E\mid B2)P(B2)}{\sum_i P(E\mid Bi)P(Bi)}\\+ \frac{P(E\mid B4)P(B4)}{\sum_i P(E\mid Bi)P(Bi)}\\&=\frac{(1-α2)(1-α4)1/4}{(1-α2)1/4 + 1/4+1/4+1/4}\\+ \frac{(1-α2)(1-α4)1/4}{(1-α4)1/4 + 1/4+1/4+1/4}.
\end{align*}
$$

Is it close to the correct answer? I'm a little bit confused..

Comment: I believe that $P(E|B_2) = 1-\alpha_2$ since we are conditioning on the fact that the key **is** in bin $2$ since for all other bins $j$, $\alpha_j=0$ given the condition.

Comment: @Partick, thank you for your observation. Does it seem right otherwise?

Comment: Your initial steps are correct but the denominators are actually wrong too.  Specifically, $P(E|B_1)=P(E|B_3)=1$ since you cannot possibly find the key someplace it is not. Similarly, $P(E|B_4)=1-\alpha_4$ like the probability conditioning on $B_2$. Now make these changes and add the two terms and you have your answer.

Comment: Also, your definition of $E$ should really say "or" instead of "and".

Comment: @Partick, the problem says that you look in both bins, that's why I'm defining "and" for E, but now after thinking about it and your comments, should I split it to E2 and E4 instead? E2 - looked in 2 and don't find in 2, E4 - look in 4 and don't find in 4. If such, I will need to find: $$
\begin{align*}
P(B2\cup B4\mid E2 \cap E4 ).
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: To me, when you say "event that you do not find the key in bins 2 **and** 4 after examining these two bins"  this implies that the key could be in both.  This is kind of just me being nitpicky.  My apologies.

Comment: @Patrick, so does this seem to be correct (after your comments):  $$
\begin{align*}
\frac{(1-α2)1/4}{(1-α2)1/4 + 1/4+(1-α4)1/4+1/4}\\+ \frac{(1-α4)1/4}{(1-α2)1/4 + 1/4+(1-α4)1/4+1/4}\\.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Yes, this agrees with my posted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B_i$ and $E$ make sense as you have defined them (with the exception of the "and" vs "or" case I mentioned in comments).

You are correct in setting up: $P(B_2 \cup B_4 |E)=\frac{P(E|B_2)P(B_2)+P(E|B_4)P(B_4)}{\sum_{i}{}P(E|B_i)P(B_i)}$

$P(E|B_i) = 1$ if $i \ne 2, 4$ since if the key is not in $2$ or $4$ you can't find it there.

$P(E|B_i) = (1-\alpha_i)$ for $i = 2,4$ since if the key is in bin $i$ the probability the $E$ happens only amounts to you not finding it in bin $i$.

$P(B_i) = \frac{1}{4} \ \forall i$

Combining this we get:

$$P(B_2 \cup B_4|E) = \frac{\frac{1}{4}(1-\alpha_2 + 1-\alpha_4)}{\frac{1}{4}(1+(1-\alpha_2)+1+(1-\alpha_4)}=\frac{2-\alpha_2 -\alpha_4}{4-\alpha_2-\alpha_4}$$